Clang format excessive amount of identation
Why does clang-format add excessive indentation or line breaks to function arguments like std::move(widget) in complex lambdas? How can I configure it to keep arguments inline or reduce unnecessary breaks?
void overlay::remove(std::variant<std::shared_ptr<widget>, std::shared_ptr<label>> &&widget) noexcept {
  std::visit([this](auto &&arg) {
    std::erase_if(_widgets, [&arg](const auto &existing) {
      return existing == arg;
    });
  },
             std::move(widget)); // This line has a excessive amount of identation
}

My .clang-format
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
Language: Cpp
UseTab: Never
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
IndentCaseLabels: false
ColumnLimit: 0
IndentWidth: 2
TabWidth: 2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
DerivePointerAlignment: False
PointerAlignment: Right
AccessModifierOffset: -2
QualifierAlignment: Left
FixNamespaceComments: False
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true

How to reduce the indentation?

It doesn't look excessive to me. The line in question is (fnally) the next argument to std::visit from what I can see. And consider a std::weak_pointer. r-value reference to a shared_ptr is weird.

And clang-format can allow short lambdas on a single line. I think that's essentially the name of the option. I don't remember if the LLVM style has that enabled by default or not.

It looks excessive because it doesn't indent the bodies of the lambdas. But it's actually aligned with the previous argument to std::visit().

@sweenish Thank you for your feedback! Is it because sol2, a wrapper for lua. I tried to change to weak and it does not work.

I have had this same problem, and could never get it to work. However, I found a bug report on this on GitHub: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56283.
It looks like this was never fixed, but there is more info here: https://reviews.llvm.org/D129443
(Took answer from another ans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74109314/16529532)
If it's applicable, I would avoid clang format and use your code editors formatter tool. If you can't that's okay.

I don't see a requires clause in the MRE. This is an adjacent issue, but not the same thing.
